# Entity Framework 6: Query Related Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am having difficulty in retrieving correctly related data from EF. This is my first time using code first to generate data so here goes my classes (stripped down for bravity)

Author.cs

```
public class Author
{
        [Key]
        public int author_id {get;set;}
        public string author_name {get;set;}
        public string author_email {get;set;}
        public virtual ICollection<AuthorCategory> AuthorCategories {get; set;}
        public Author()
        {
            this.AuthorCategories = new HashSet<AuthorCategory>();
        }
}
```

AuthorCategory.cs

```
public class AuthorCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    public string category_name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    public AuthorCategory()
    {
        this.Authors = new HashSet<Author>();
    }
}
```

AuthorRelation.cs

```
public class AuthorCategoryRelation
{
    public AuthorCategoryRelation()
    {
        this.AuthorCategories = new HashSet<AuthorCategory>();
        this.Authors = new HashSet<Author>();

    }
    public int author_id { get; set; }
    public int category_id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AuthorCategory> AuthorCategories { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

I the hope of retrieving a list of each author to output author name, email and the (possible multiple) categories each author belongs to, I run;

```
    var authors = (from a in db.Authors
                   select new
                   {
                       first_name = a.first_name,
                       last_name = a.last_name,
                       cats = a.AuthorCategories.ToList()
                   });
```

I return the resultset in JSON format. So what I expected to be a simple output turned out to be something like this

```
{
  "Authors": [
    {
      "AuthorCategories": [
        {
          "Authors": [
            {
              "AuthorCategories": [],
              "author_id": 8,
              "first_name": "Ava",
              "last_name": "Mcmillan",
              "photo_path": "C:\\Inetpub\\HwHosts\\ontayka.com\\img\\authors\\t1_ava_mcmillan.jpg",
              "photo_social_sharing": null,
              "username": "xoxywaf",
              "password": "8810160BFD79D7DE46388533E26FFD247D152514",
              "pass_guid": "7b574629-32b0-4905-b51c-4315a446e96e",
              "email": "kekozod@yahoo.com",
              "twitter": "Ut aspernatur blanditiis reprehenderit deserunt aut autem accusantium ea natus irure rerum quaerat",
              "facebook": "Voluptatem Deserunt illo in sit",
              "date_created": "2016-08-16T17:31:50.383",
              "date_last_login": null,
              "author_status": 0,
              "about_author": "Qui quis laboriosam, pariatur? In in est, sunt optio, sit, quia et.",
              "require_publish_approval": true,
              "column_name": null,
              "column_image": null,
              "change_password_at_first_login": false,
              "tenant_id": 1,
              "Posts": null
            }
          ],
          "category_id": 2,
          "category_name": "Ekonomi",
          "tenant_id": 0
        }
      ],
      "author_id": 7,
      "first_name": "Caryn",
      "last_name": "Hines",
      "photo_path": "C:\\Inetpub\\HwHosts\\ontayka.com\\img\\authors\\t1_caryn_hines.jpg",
      "photo_social_sharing": null,
      "username": "jocusadom",
      "password": "609DE1F0C08B8FC4A797E381A160A64285A3F1D8",
      "pass_guid": "324bf75b-f22e-486f-905d-45623f34a09b",
      "email": "favojyj@hotmail.com",
      "twitter": "Sed aliquid dolores veniam explicabo In proident rem sit nisi fugiat laboris nisi esse aut",
      "facebook": "Magnam dolorum voluptatem atque voluptate assumenda velit rerum ducimus itaque eos aut",
      "date_created": "2016-08-16T17:30:46.44",
      "date_last_login": null,
      "author_status": 1,
      "about_author": "Deserunt et consequatur, fuga. Dolores et fugit, exercitationem alias fugiat iusto adipisicing nemo ullam eaque harum nemo sit, dignissimos.",
      "require_publish_approval": false,
      "column_name": null,
      "column_image": null,
      "change_password_at_first_login": false,
      "tenant_id": 1,
      "Posts": null
    }
  ],
  "category_id": 1,
  "category_name": "Spor",
  "tenant_id": 0
}
```

Obviously something is definitely wrong here. I would really appreciate any experienced devs out there to guide me on this. I am defining the classed wrong? or is it something else that I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you producing the JSON?

Comment: First of all, you do not need `AuthorRelation` class, since EntityFramework will create relation table itself. Secondly, it is recomended to turn of LazyLoading when serializing your objects.

Comment: AuthorRelation class is indeed needed to correctly map Authors to Categories. Though, it is not accessible from code since the corresponding database table is created by ToTable mapping during OnModelCreating, if that's what you are saying.

Comment: Henry, the json is serialised in my action but why does that matter?